# Storing $(this) in a variable

Tags: jquery

If I want to save `this` as a jQuery DOM object and then select it, which method below should I use?

```
var element = $(this)
```

And then for selecting

```
$(element)
```

Or simply

```
var element = this
```

Also, if I want then to concatenate `element` into a larger selector, is this:

```
$(element + " .class")
```

the right way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var element = $(this)
```

Then you can use `element` instead of `$(this)`. You don't have to insert `element` into `$()` anymore.

For example : `element.remove()` instead of `$(this).remove()`

Comment: To achieve the edit `$(element + " .class")` with the above answer use `element.hasClass("class")`

Comment: A good practice is to name your variables with a ```$``` then you immediately know it's a jQuery object.

Answer (score 12):

`$this = $(this)` is usually what people do. The dollar sign is a valid character for a variable name, so it serves as a good reminder that the variable is a jQuery object.

You can then use `$this` as you would any jQuery element. For example, `$this.css('border', 'none')`

Comment: Should be careful with this, particularly if the reason for storing it in a variable is to refer to it in a different context (secondary click event, AJAX result) where `$(this)` refers to something different.

Comment: @jim, true. It can get confusing when you want to refer to $this inside an AJAX success function or some such.

Comment: +1, although I prefer using `$that` as when I use this I usually need it in another scope that already uses a different `this` - basically to be less confusing.

Comment: That's clever @Louis, i might start doing that

Comment: Pretty sure I picked it up from JS the good parts, wouldn't give me too much praise over it :P

Answer (score 2):

`var element = $(this)` for storing

then `element` for selecting

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select all items with class myClass, you should do:

```
var $this = $(this);
var myClassElements = $(".myClass", $this);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I do, and frankly superior (and correct) compared to other answers.

Comment: @OlliM won't `myClassElements` select `this` inside `myClass`?

Comment: Should be careful with this, particularly if the reason for storing it in a variable is to refer to it in a different context (secondary click event, AJAX result) where $(this) refers to something different.

Comment: @IlyaD this is given as context for the selector, so jQuery will only find elements inside it. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 1):

The right way is:

```
var element= this.html();
$(element).find(div) /* from modefy div you can change it with any other selector */
$(element).attr({"class":"myClass","other atrribut":"it's value"});
```

I hope that is useful.