# Is it okay to store the result of a JQuery selector in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Developers I know tend to call the same JQuery selectors over and over instead of storing the result in a variable. They are consistent with this approach.

For example, they do this:

```
var propName = $(this).attr('data-inv-name');
var propValue = $(this).attr('data-inv-value');
```

Instead of this:

```
var current = $(this);
var propName = current.attr('data-inv-name');
var propValue = current.attr('data-inv-value');
```

The latter approach feels correct to me but maybe I'm missing something. This is a simple example, but I've seen $(this) repeated dozens of times in the same function.

What is the best practice for development with JQuery? Call selectors repeatedly or store in a variable?

Comment: It's actually good practice to store elements in variables rather than looking them up in the DOM if you're going to use them over and over again, however when it comes to `this` it's a special kind of internal variable that isn't looked up again, so it's already cached, and probably better than most things, but you would save a function call to jQuery.

Comment: And dupe -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432228/storing-this-in-a-variable

Comment: Not really a dupe. The example I gave was `$(this)` but I'm asking about selectors in general. `$('#someid')`, `$('.someclass')`, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shown analysis is a micro optimization. Using `$(this)` repeatedly versus storing `$(this)` in a variable and reusing it will not cause a significant hit to performance.

The times you really want to store the result is when there is an actual selector in there. The only hit you are taking by repeatedly calling `$(this)` is calling the jQuery constructor function which is very lightweight.

So in this instance go with what reads better. If there really is a *dozen* occurrences of `$(this)` in a row, then there should have either been some storing of the variable as indicated, or more likely there was an opportunity to take advantage of chaining which was missed.

Comment: Also a great response . . . if there is ever a time that I deviate from what **godmode** put in his answer, it's when I'm using `$(this)` . . . it's the act of selecting that you are really trying to avoid repeating, and, honestly, in a lot of ways, "this" is very descriptive, in your logic.

Comment: I've seen the repetition with and without a selector. I'll keep an eye out for repeated selectors and use variables but will leave `$(this)` alone. Good answer and thank you.

Answer (score 11):

If I'm going to use the same selector more than twice I always create a variable. The one change I would recommend is using $ before your variable name to signify that it is a jQuery object

```
var $current = $(this);
var propName = $current.attr('data-inv-name');
var propValue = $current.attr('data-inv-value');
```

Comment: I do this as well, but, for me, it's if I use it more than once.

Comment: Agreed. I also tend to store $(this) in a descriptive variable whenever I nest event callback functions and it's unclear what $(this) is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

In theory selecting the component many times demands more process then using one you already have...

If you don't have too many selectors in your page the diference will be almost null (I guess this is the more commom case)... Then you can think about what makes it more readable or easy to modify...

Sometimes you use the same element in a dozen of lines, in this case I prefer to assign this to a variable because when the element change I will need to change just one line (the line I assigned the variable)...